# Drupal Node Forms - Image field: How to directly upload an image after choosing a file (no need to click upload button)

Tags: image, drupal-7, field

I'm trying to change the default behavior of Drupal when adding an image through image field on a content type.

When you choose an image to assign to a node, it's not directly uploaded. You also need to click "upload" to display the preview of your image, and this is not really user friendly.

How can I change this (programmatically) to make Drupal start uploading directly the image after choosing the file.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.autoUpload = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.form-item input.form-submit[value=Upload]', context).hide();
      $('.form-item input.form-file', context).change(function() {
        $parent = $(this).closest('.form-item');
        setTimeout(function() {
          if(!$('.error', $parent).length) {
            $('input.form-submit[value=Upload]', $parent).mousedown();
          }
        }, 100);
      });


      $('.form-item input.form-submit[value=Transférer]', context).hide();
      $('.form-item input.form-file', context).change(function() {
        $parent = $(this).closest('.form-item');
        setTimeout(function() {
          if(!$('.error', $parent).length) {
            $('input.form-submit[value=Transférer]', $parent).mousedown();
          }
        }, 100);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

This solution works with either english and french browsers. Unlike [AutoUpload](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoupload) module, which only works on browsers configured in english. Note the `[value=Upload]` / `[value=Upload]` attribute

I found a similar post:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31121/how-can-i-automatically-upload-images-on-file-selection-rather-than-pressing-the

It's exactly what I need..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use http://drupal.org/project/imce for your needs.

I am not sure about the Image field but when I encountered this issue I decided letting users add images in body since it is a much easier option for durpal - When inserting images in text They will show immediately .

IMCE + filefield seems like a viable option for your direct needs,They do mention AJAX support.